# How does a UInt128, relate to the 2 UInt64s it's comprised of?

Tags: swift, long-integer

If I have the following struct:

```
public struct UInt128 {
    internal var value: (upperBits: UInt64, lowerBits: UInt64)
}
```

Imagine an initializer that creates a random number that fits into `UInt128` and that number is sufficiently large such that it exceeds the value of one of the `UInt64`

Do the upper bits and the lower bits sum to be the total of the `UInt128` or the memory managed in another way?

For the sake of working with small numbers, if the capacity of each `UInt64` is 20, If the value of the `UInt128` was 24, would the upper bits value be 20 and the lower bits value be 4?

Comment: The capacity of a UInt64 is 2^64 or 18,446,744,073,709,551,616. You would get better answers if you describe what you are trying to accomplish. It would be easier to see how this works using UInt16 and two UInt8 values.

Comment: Sure. I should have used smaller ints. I’m just trying to understand the memory allocation under the hood.

Comment: Memory allocation is a little more complicated, there are two basic schemes: big-endian and little-endian, see [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Intel uses little-endian while network byte order is big-endian.

Comment: Sorry, memory allocation was the wrong term. Take a UInt16, made up to 2 UInt8s. Each UInt8 has a capacity of 255. So if the upper bits are 255 and the lower bits are 5, does that mean the value of the UInt16 is 260? Or something entirely different?

Comment: Memory allocation is a little more complicated: Take hex 41424343 and display as characters on a big-endian machine and you get "ABCD", displayed on a little-endian machine you get "DCBA".

Comment: I sense you are still not getting it.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine you are asked to make a `struct` that represents 4-digit numbers, but you can only store 2-digit numbers.  So, you have an `upperHalf` that represents the first 2 digits and a `lowerHalf` that represents the second 2 digits.

```
let upperHalf = 12
let lowerHalf = 34
```

Now, you want to combine them to make the full 4-digit number `1234`.

How do you do that?  Do you add them?

```
12 + 34 = 46
```

No, because the 12 doesn't just represent `12`.  It is really `1200`.

```
1200 + 34 = 1234
```

So in order to combine them, you multiply the `upperHalf` by `100` to *make space* for the lower digits and then add the `lowerHalf`.

```
let upperHalf = 12
let lowerHalf = 34
let value = upperHalf * 100 + lowerHalf
print(value)  // 1234
```

So, what is `100`?  It represents shifting a base-10 number left 2 places.  For each shift, you multiply by `10`.  So `2` shifts is `10 * 10` or `100`.

Now you are given the task of using two `UInt8` numbers to represent a `UInt16` number.

```
let upperBits = 2
let lowerBits = 1
```

Now you want to combine them to make the `UInt16` value.  Like in the previous case, you can't just add them.  You need to shift the `upperBits` over to the left by `8` places to make room for the `lowerBits`.  But now you are using binary (base 2), so every shift is accomplished by multiplying by `2`.

So combining the `upperBits` and `lowerBits` of two `UInt8` values becomes

```
let value = (upperBits * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2) + lowerBits
```

which is the same as:

```
let value = (upperBits * 256) + lowerBits
```

which can also be written as:

```
let value = (upperBits << 8) + lowerBits
```

`<< 8` means shift the bits left `8` times.

So if `upperBits` is `2` and `lowerBits` is `1` then

```
let value = (2 * 256) + 1  // value = 513
```

---

Extending this analogy to using two `UInt64` numbers to represent a `UInt128`, you need to shift the `upperBits` 64 places to the left before adding the `lowerBits`.  Each shift is the same as multiplying by `2`, so you have to multiply `upperBits` by `2 ^ 64` (or `18446744073709551616`) to make room before adding `lowerBits`:

Conceptually:

```
let value: UInt128 = (upperBits << 64) + lowerBits
```

Which is the same as:

```
let value: UInt128 = (upperBits * 18446744073709551616) + lowerBits
```

Comment: This is just what I’m looking for! Thank you!

Comment: So this applied to a 256 bit integer would be (upper << 128) + lower

Comment: Amazing. Thank you @vacawama!

Comment: By the way, Swift is supposed to have a special type for this, [DoubleWidth](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/DoubleWidth.swift.gyb). However, it seems it didn't make it to Swift 4.

Comment: @Sulthan I was looking into that. DoubleWidth was taken out before Swift 3.2 because it was slow and is reimplemented to be released in early 2018 in Swift 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Consider two UInt8 memory locations with the value in the most-significant 00000001 and the value 00000010 in the least-significant that in a correct order joined UInt16 as 0000000100000010 which is 258. The left most 8 bits representing 256 and the right most 2, 256 + 2 = 258. Or looking at just the 16-bit UInt16 the first (left) 1 represents 256 and the last (right) 1 represents 2.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for all of your help zaph. Really appreciate it. Added a helpful link I found as well

Comment: So then extrapolating that to a UInt128, made up of 2 UInt64s, the sum of the ints in the 64s always equals the 128 value, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think any answer you’re going to get is going to be a vast oversimplification given the question, but here’s my take:

The lower bits would represent the numbers 0 to 2^64-1 and the upper bits would represent the numbers 2^64 to 2^128-1

If you had two 64 bit numbers and wanted to add them together, you would shift the higher bits 64 bits to the left.

Does that help your understanding?

Comment: It’s getting there. Thanks for the answer, Dave. So would the total number represented in the UInt128 be the upper bits + the lower bits or something else?

Comment: @ZackShapiro, in this simplified version, it would be lower bits + (upper bits * 2^64)